# How to call php file using cgi in html?

Tags: php, html, cgi

I have used below mentioned code :

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>test Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <!--#exec cgi="calc.php" -->
 <table>
  <tr> 
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td><img src="images1.jpg"></td>
   <td><img src="images2.jpg"></td>
   <td><img src="images3.jpg"></td>
   </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td colspan=3><img src="common.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

If I use above mentioned code it show

> [an error occurred while processing this directive]

error in front end, now what I have to do should I configure in cpanel and htaccess ?

Comment: I don't get it. What is the purpose ? Can't you just include calc.php ?

Comment: i have to run calc.php file using exec in every file.

Comment: I got the intention from your question. My question is why run calc.php using exec ?

Comment: doing calculation and passing value to every file to place order